# Finite subcover of an open cover with common boundary point

Tags: analysis, compactness, geometric-topology

Let $S$ be a set of open sets. Suppose all open sets in $S$ have a common boundary point. That is, $\exists$ a point $p$ such that $\forall s\in S$, $p$ is a boundary point of $s$. It is known that $S$ is an open cover for $Ω$ \ {$p$}, where $Ω$ is a compact set. Is it true that there is always a finite subcover of $S$ for $Ω$ \ {$p$}?

I has thought about it in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and I think that it should be true. But I failed to find a satisfying answer for this. Is there any way to apply Heine-Borel Property for this? Or could this has any ways to solve?

Comment: When you just cannot find a proof of something, you should try your hardest to disprove it instead - usually by constructing a counter-example. Either you will succeed in disproving it, or the reasons that prevent you from disproving it may give you new insight in how to prove it. Mathematicians sometimes go through several alternations of attempting to prove or disprove before reaching a conclusion. In this case, remember that even though $\Omega$ is compact, $\Omega \setminus \{p\}$ need not be.

Answer (score 0):

In $\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$, the one-point compactification of $\mathbb R$, consider the complements of the closed sets $C_k=\{\infty\}\cup\{n\ge k\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ for $k\in\mathbb N$. They all have $\infty$ as a boundary point, and they cover $\mathbb R$, but there’s no finite subcover.